# AppEngine Modules to subdomain

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to know how I can point one of my module in appengine to a subdomain. For example:

```
module-one.myapp.appspot.com -> mydomain.com
module-two.myapp.appspot.com -> two.mydomain.com
```

Solution:

1. How @svpino say you have to set a wildcard.
2. Then you have to have something like this on your dispatch.yaml:

   > url: "two.mydomain.com/*"
3. And finally you have to create a custom domain name in the settings of App Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up a wildcard subdomain: For example: *.app.example.com. You can read more about how to do this in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more_about_wildcard_subdomain_mapping

> If you set up a wildcard subdomain mapping for your custom domain,
>   then your application serves requests for any subdomain that matches.
>
> If the user browses a domain that matches an application version name
>   or backend name, the application serves that version. If the user
>   browses a domain that matches a backend name, the application serves
>   that backend. For example, suppose you set up a wildcard subdomain
>   *.wild.example.com. Your application has two versions, the default version and one named beta. Your application has a backend server
>   named be with just one backend instance running.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CDN like cloudflare for that. You define a DNS rules like you want. If you don't need HTTPS you can define 3 DNS rules for free. If you need HTTPS the cost is 20$ per month and you can define more DNS rules. Using a CDN reduce the usage cost for your application and add many improvement.